# Work with duplicate sets and reset binary variable within groups

Tags: duplicates, stata

I have data of the following type (the other variables can be completely random):

```
Name  Member  Other variables
 AAA    0
 AAA    0
 AAA    1
 BBB    0
 BBB    0
 CCC    1
```

Note that the `1` can occur in a group of duplicates at any location, but only one will occur per block of duplicates.

I would like to eliminate duplicates as follows:

- If member is `1`, no need to worry, no duplicates problem (e.g., `CCC`).
- If member is `0` for all duplicates, that's alright too (e.g., `BBB`)
- if member has `1` and the rest `0`, then all other rows for that duplicate set needs to be made equal to `1`.

I have tried looking at using `duplicates`, custom routines using `_N`, `_n` etc., but none of them work since I don't know how to loop over one set of duplicates at a time (have also looked into `foreach`, etc).

The final result should look like this:

```
Name  Member  Other variables
 AAA    1
 AAA    1
 AAA    1
 BBB    0
 BBB    0
 CCC    1
```

One thing I was thinking of was that if I can somehow work with one group at a time, I can apply `max()` to the member column for each block of duplicates, and that will yield what I want.  However, the issue is that I don't know how to work with one group at a time.

Bonus:

If I can also eliminate duplicates after this change and arrive at the set below, that will be a nice bonus. But I think that I know how to get there once the above step is clear.

```
Name  Member  Other variables
AAA    1
BBB    0
CCC    1
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
clear

input str3 Name  Member
AAA 0
AAA 0
AAA 1
BBB 0
BBB 0
CCC 1
end

bysort Name (Member) : egen Wanted1 = max(Member)
```

or

```
bysort Name (Member) : generate Wanted2 = Member[_N]
```

Both produce the desired output:

```
list, sepby(Name)

     +-----------------------------------+
     | Name   Member   Wanted1   Wanted2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |  AAA        0         1         1 |
  2. |  AAA        0         1         1 |
  3. |  AAA        1         1         1 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  4. |  BBB        0         0         0 |
  5. |  BBB        0         0         0 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  6. |  CCC        1         1         1 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```

Note that `_n` runs from `1` to `_N` in any (sub)set of observations. As such,
`_N` always indexes the *last* observation.

Bonus:

```
bysort Name (Member) : drop if (Wanted1 == 1 & Name == Name[_n-1]) | ///
                               (Wanted1 == 0 & Name == Name[_n-1])

list, sepby(Name)

     +-----------------------------------+
     | Name   Member   Wanted1   Wanted2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |  AAA        0         1         1 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  2. |  BBB        0         0         0 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  3. |  CCC        1         1         1 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider up-voting it with the upper arrow and accepting it using the check-mark.